# Any issue with compareAndSet method in AtomicBoolean?

Tags: java, concurrency

I have encountered with one issue with compareAndSet of AtomicBoolean class.
I cannot post my code in this forum. But I will explain the scenario.

> 1) I have Two mutual exclusive features of one functionality.
>
> 2) Both feature have their own cap i.e. a user can use the feature for X number of times only. For example sake, assume that user can use first feature 4 times and second feature 2 times
>
> 3) First feature is enabled for 50 minutes of the hour i.e. second feature is disabled during that time
>
> 4) Second feature is enabled in last 10 minutes of the hour i.e first feature is disabled during that time
>
> 5) Both these features are using same AtomicBoolean attribute ("in progress"). This boolean will check user's earlier request is in progress or not. If user's earlier request is in progress, it will show message : "Your request is already in progress" and boolean will be marked as "true". Once his request is processed, the boolean will turn to "false". A user can re-request the feature only when "in progress" is false.
>
> 6) During switch over from first feature to second feature, a particular user got issue. User used first feature for max cap. Now he is trying to use second feature but got a message "Your request is already in progress" even though it is first request for accessing second feature.

This happens only when AtomicBoolean is not reset by first feature. The application ran fine for over 3 months but I have received complaint from one user.

On receiving user request, I got a doubt on "AtomicBoolean"'s compareAndSet method usage. Is there any possible bug with this API? Have you ever encountered any issues with this API? I have not encountered any exceptions/errors in log file

Comment: Without knowing how/when/etc you're using it I'm not sure how anybody could help. You can check the Java bug tracker(s) for specific API issues.

Comment: Looks like no development happened in this class (AtomicBoolean) from last 3-4 years. Except for documentation conflict, no issues have been reported

Comment: Well, probably not then. I'd actually be pretty surprised if it was a library issue as opposed to its usage. It's certainly *possible*, but...

Comment: If you can post an example of the flow we may be able to help.  It's just too hard to tell based on the description despite how much time you put into it.

Comment: I will add pseudo code in 1 hour

Comment: Go ahead and blame `AtomicBoolean`, but all it will do is cost you time and effort. It is your code which has a race condition, so I advise you to concentrate on finding and resolving that issue. As for the code you are not allowed to post, we are actually _expecting_ you not to post your complex production code, but a small, focused, self-contained, _runnable_  example which is able to reproduce your issue. No reproduction---no problem.

Comment: You got my point., The use case spans over 20+ classes and issue has been reported for once in 3 months. Due to this reason, I just want to find out anyone getting issues with AtomicBoolean. Due to regulatory constraints, even one user complaint will be taken for serious consideration

Comment: Now I am thinking of splitting AtomicBoolean for each use case. At least it will resolve any overlapping issues between two features.

Comment: _I cannot post my code in this forum. But..._ For something as simple as AtomicBoolean, you could almost certainly reduce it to an SSCCE (http://sscce.org/), and you might even figure out the answer for yourself in the process.

Comment: How are you counting feature usage?  I assume that you're using a `volatile int` or `AtomicInteger` that isn't properly tied to the `AtomicBoolean`, i.e. you're flipping the `AtomicBoolean` without ensuring that you flip the `volatile int / AtomicInteger`.  Either use a `synchronized` block / method to ensure that everything gets flipped, or figure out a way to use an `AtomicReference` to do the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt very much the problem is with the code in Java's Atomic Boolean class.

Almost certainly the problem is in the code that calls the AtomicBoolean.  The way you describe the checking for whether an earlier request is in progress suggests that the problem may be in improper synchronization of the code that does this checking.  A Java AtomicBoolean won't "check user's earlier request" for you, so you must have written the code that does so; you might try asking for a review of that code from someone who is experienced in multithreaded code.

The fact that the problem only showed up after months of proper operation is in fact quite typical of how concurrency bugs show up.  They are often very intermittent.  This is another indication that is likely a race condition in your code.

You really need to provide excerpts from your code if you want further help.

Answer (score 0):

`compareAndSet` method of `AtomicBoolean` does not have any issue. I found the issue with application flow.

I am sharing my experience so that you may not land in same type of issue.

I have found a path in application, where the boolean was set as true for the first feature. During an error scenario, the flag was not reset. In normal scenario, the flag was re-set properly. Once the flag is re-set, second feature will work in normal way as per expectations.

Since getting this error is very infrequent, application ran fine for some months. Once I got the error scenario, second feature was not enabled since flag was not re-set in exception scenario.

After re-setting the boolean in all possible cases ( success & failure), this scenario is not repeated. My suspicion about AtomicBoolean has become false.